# mysql search on match

Tags: mysql

Please check my following table structure...

```
| id  | r_num   |
+-----+---------+
| 9   | 2011/9  |
+-----+---------+
| 10  | 2012/2  |
+-----+---------+
```

And want to get all rows for given year, and i have tried following query...

```
SELECT * from tblr WHERE r_num = 2011;
```

But above query is not giving expected results, should i use LIKE or what is the best way to achieve desired results. Please help, thanks.

Comment: What type is the `r_num` column? Is it `date`, or `datetime`, or just a string?

Comment: yes you have to use like, but if the column r_num is datetime then you can use WHERE r_num >= '2011' AND r_num < '2012' othervise see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from tblr WHERE r_num like '2011%';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in your case-

```
SELECT * from tblr WHERE r_num like '2011/%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your r_num is a datetime type :

```
SELECT * FROM tblr WHERE r_num >= '2011' AND r_num < '2012';
```

else

```
SELECT * FROM tblr WHERE r_num LIKE '2011%';
```

It's a basic question, you can find many documentations on mysql website : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html